# SQL Partition by case statement and flag

Tags: sql

I have run into an issue,

the table is partitioned by col2 by values, BB and CC, and the have their respective status in col3, what i want is to apply a flag for every row in col2, e.g if any or all rows in col2 has status 'ST_Inprogress' or 'ST_Approved' then flag for all the rows in col2 should be 'Y' else it should be 'N' like given table in the attached picture

[image]

Could someone please help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

With `MAX()` window function:

```
select *,
  max(case when Col3 in ('ST_Inprogress', 'ST_Approved') then 'Y' else 'N' end) over (partition by Col2) flag
from tablename
```

See the demo for [Postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=1121f416a1016e9f9ceb703f58c34d09) and for [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3adba8c0c8dade029132f0d587bdcf1e).
Results:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3        | flag |
| ---- | ---- | ----------- | ---- |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Closed   | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Closed   | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Closed   | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | BB   | ST_Deleted  | N    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Approved | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Deleted  | Y    |
| AA   | CC   | ST_Approved | Y    |
```